# InnoSetup - fails. Unable to execute file in the temporary directory. Setup aborted. Error 5: Access is denied

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, mcafee

When user install my InnoSetup file. They get

[image]

When user shut down all McAfee policy then it works. Is there anyway to fix it without having to shut down McAfee policy?

Comment: Do you have administrator privileges? I.E. `RunAsAdmin`?

Comment: How to detect that if i have administrator privileges? if yes no msgbox, if no then show innoSetup msgbox "sorry, we cant help you. use RunAsAdmin" ?

Comment: `IsAdminLoggedOn` may be what you need.